# FragmentManager tries to find the old package name of the project and gives "No view found for fragment"

Tags: java, android

In my activity page, I have a `Button` to call a `Fragment`. `FragmentManager` tries to call that `fragment`'s newInstance function.

It used to work well but from some point in the project, I needed to change its name to something else because its name was `testObjectBlaBla` and I needed to release it to Play Store so I changed its package name. But now it gives

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900d0
>   (com.myblabla.example:id/fragment_container) for fragment
>   MarkerSpecification_Vehi{18103143 #0 id=0x7f0900d0 BLANK_FRAGMENT}

I tried to change the package name back to the old one but still but I can't change the name every time I want to go live.

```
    MarkerSpecification_Acco fragment =MarkerSpecification_Acco.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_right,R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_right);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment,"BLANK_FRAGMENT").commit();
```

Not sure if this is the true piece because exception not giving any error in my own code but in `fragmentManager.java` class instead. Probably bacause trying to search the old package name `com.myblabla.example` instead of `com.project.project`. But I think it is the only place where the code tries to find a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you change the calling of the fragment to this:

`Fragment frag = new MarkerSpecification_Acco();`

Also check in your XML File if your container reference has changed to your new Fragment name.

Comment: Thanks! Even though your first suggestion not worked, after checking my XML container reference, I realized for some reason android studio still keeps the old reference ID for that view and that's why it can't be found. I reinitialized the view element and solved the issue!